# Path to Kubernetes cluster CA cert and ca cert private key

Tags: kubernetes

export K8s cluster CA cert and CA private key

Team, I have a Kubernetes cluster running. I will be deleting and creating it again and again so I want to reuse the same CA cert all the time for which I need to save the CA cert and key to create secret as below

```
create secret keypair ca --cert ${CACRT} --key ${CAKEY} --name ${NAME}
```

Need path to the cert and key and also kops command to export them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish with the `create secret keypair ca...` command, but you can get these right out of one of the Kubernetes masters (or master if you have one).

```
$ ssh user@kubernetesmaster
```

Then:

```
$ cat /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
...
$ cat /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key
```

Note that `etcd` usually uses a different CA. You can find it under:

```
/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd
```

Comment: I got it: root ca and key of k8s is /svr/kubernetes/ca.key and ca.crt